# Error type mismatch while using generics in scala

Tags: scala, scala-generics

Getting errors while using generics in scala:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class test {
  val car = mutable.Map.emprty[String, (Int,Int)]
  read[String, (Int,Int)] ("file.txt",car)
  def read[T,V] (fileName:String, mapName: mutable.Map[T,V]) {
    mapName("abc") = (1,2)
  }
```

Error:

```
   error: type mismatch
   found: java.lang.String("abc")
   required: T
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't really generic, because inside `read` function body, you are assuming `T` and `V` to be `String` and `(Int, Int)`. The generic parameters are bounds on your method signature and they are only useful when types of arguments or return types relate in some way to each other.

I think with your code will be perfectly fine to use concrete types in the `read` function signature:

```scala
def read(fileName: String, mapName: mutable.Map[String, (Int, Int)]) {
  mapName("abc") = (1,2)
}
```